# Compiling and Installing Matlab package

Tags: matlab

I have a Mac OS with Maverick. I would like to use an (unofficial) Matlab package. I am trying to follow instructions in the README file but I have difficulties (I am not a programmer at all). Here is the text :

"To run sparsenet, you will first need to compile the conjugate
gradient (cgf) routine so that it may be called through matlab.  To do
this, you will first need to build the library libnrfopt.a, which
contains the actual conjugate gradient subroutines.  Go to the nrf/
subdirectory and type

```
make libnrfopt.a
```

Then go back up the to sparsenet directory and compile the cgf routine
so that it may be called by matlab.  First modify the makefile
definition for MEXT to be the proper suffix for the mex file for your
machine (for SGI's it is mexsg).  Then type

```
make
```

If successful, this should create a file named cgf.xxx, where xxx is a
suffix that depends on what machine you are on."

I could do the first step ("make libnrfopt.a). But I just do not understand the sentence " First modify the makefile
definition for MEXT to be the proper suffix for the mex file for your
machine (for SGI's it is mexsg)".

Please, anyone could explain me what to do ?

In advance, thank you very very.
Julien

Answer (score 1):

If you open the makefile with a text editor you may be able to comment out the irrelevant MEXT suffix's and make sure your machines' is selected and then procede.

Comment: The codes in the makefile is : `MEX = mex
NRFDIR = ./nrf
MEXT = mexsg

cgf.$(MEXT): cgf.c
 $(MEX) -I$(NRFDIR) -L$(NRFDIR) -lnrfopt cgf.c``
What should I comment out exactly given that I am working with a macbook OS Maverick (do not know if it is important)? Thanks  !!!

Comment: Is this the sparsenet package from Berkeley? : http://redwood.berkeley.edu/bruno/sparsenet/ if so are you trying to install from the .zip or .tar?

Comment: Hi, I dont have enough reputation to commnet below. It looks like it cant find mex still. Id the location NRFDIR = ./nrf correct in the makefile? I'm not sure what to suggest apart from contacting the developer directly: Bruno Olshausen: bruno@ai.mit.edu